# How to integrate Ngin-x with APC and php

Tags: nginx, centos6, alternative-php-cache

I'm running a PHP script on a Nginx server. I've installed APC but I'm not sure whether it's working with Nginx or not

My server is CentOS with cPanel. I have full control and root access. What should I do to integrate APC with Nginx to enable running PHP scripts?

Answer (score 4):

APC (advanced php cache) works with PHP, not Nginx.

You may know from phpinfo script, that apc extension is used; specifically, save this code as a .php file and view it through the web:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

to get php and apc to work, all you need to do is install the php5-apc rpm. I'm not sure how cPanel works, but if you can add the IUS repository (http://iuscommunity.org/) you can just install the php53u-* rpms, with php-fpm.